# This site can’t provide a secure connectionwww.000webhost.com sent an invalid response. ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR

Tags: mysql, server, hosting

In my 000webhost account c-panerl is not working. Whenever I try to login with my email and password It's showing this error message. My email and password was correct too.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aWhi.png)

I'v tried changing the security settings from the browser but it didn't work.

Comment: It is the website, that is sending false information. But this looks more like a case for the support, as you can do nothing on the client side

Answer (score 0):

Seconded; I'm having the same issue as well, I'm surprised that Hostinger / 000Webhost has clearly allowed there SSL certificate to expire, yet they haven't bothered updating it, nor renewing it. That's why we're facing this "secure connection failed" error though. As others have already stated, there is nothing we can do about it until 000Webhost updates there SSL certificate on their login page for the c-panel. (Which really sucks...)

My best advice would be to bombard the support team at 000Webhost until they fix it.....

EDIT: Hostinger owns 000Webhost, so the only way to talk to any kind of support team over at 000Webhost is by making a Hostinger account, and going to the help section at https://hpanel.hostinger.com/help. At the bottom of the help page there's a section that says "Can't find an answer? Select a topic and get in touch with our Success team". You're gonna wanna click "Site is down, slow, or displaying an error" and then select "I cannot access my website". From there it will take you to a chatbox where you can message a Hostinger Support Representative. Explain to them that you're unable to access your 000Webhost account and cpanel due to a "secure connection failed" error. The more people who report this to the support team the faster the issue will get resolved. Because we need to show a high level of precedent with this issue in order for the support team to do anything about it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).